# How to build a grpc server and client binary for both target and host with Yocto

Tags: grpc, yocto, openembedded

I have a cmake project which is building in yocto on an x86 host, and deploying to an arm device. The project has a grpc client and server binary, and I would like my build host to be able to be the client to the arm device with the server binary. I was wondering what the best way is to compile the client and server binaries for both architectures in yocto. My main question is if I can utilize the sources yocto fetches for building for the host. Or do I need to build the cmake project and clone the sources myself without help from yocto if I want these binaries built for the host architecture?